# Magento 2 : Create configurable product programmatically

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, magento2.3.1

I want to create configurable product with simple product assign.

It should be working same as like create from admin.

I have tried so many tutorials and answers. But, it's not working.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way...

```
<?php 

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '5G');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

/**
 * If the external file is in the root folder
 */
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$params = $_SERVER;

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // instance of object manager


            $category_id= array(67,68);

            //$imglist = implode(',', $insert_csv['image']);
            //echo $imagelist = array($imglist);

            $configurable_product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
            $configurable_product->setSku("test-sku"); // set sku
            $configurable_product->setName("test-name"); // set name
            $configurable_product->setAttributeSetId(4);
            $configurable_product->setStatus(1);
            $configurable_product->setTypeId('configurable');
            $configurable_product->setVisibility(4);
            $configurable_product->setPrice(0);
            $configurable_product->setWebsiteIds(array(1)); // set website
            $configurable_product->setCategoryIds($category_id); // set category
            $configurable_product->setStockData(array(
                'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
                'manage_stock' => 1, //manage stock
                'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
                    )
            );

            // super attribute 
            $size_attr_id = $configurable_product->getResource()->getAttribute('size')->getId();
            $color_attr_id = $configurable_product->getResource()->getAttribute('color')->getId();

            $configurable_product->getTypeInstance()->setUsedProductAttributeIds(array($color_attr_id, $size_attr_id), $configurable_product); //attribute ID of attribute 'size_general' in my store

            $configurableAttributesData = $configurable_product->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($configurable_product);
            $configurable_product->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
            $configurable_product->setConfigurableAttributesData($configurableAttributesData);
            $configurableProductsData = array();
            $configurable_product->setConfigurableProductsData($configurableProductsData);
            try {
                $configurable_product->save();
            } catch (Exception $ex) {
                echo '<pre>';
                print_r($ex->getMessage());
                exit;
            }

            $productId = $configurable_product->getId();



            // assign simple product ids

            $associatedProductIds = array(4609,4610,4611,4612);

            try{
            $configurable_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId); // Load Configurable Product
                $configurable_product->setAssociatedProductIds($associatedProductIds); // Setting Associated Products
                $configurable_product->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
                $configurable_product->save();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($e->getMessage());
                exit;
            }
```

Comment: Which type of associated product should be here?

Comment: I run this script. But, it doesn't assign simple product in configurable product.

Comment: @Niket i think you have missmetch in attribute color,size

Comment: If i want to create that simple product with that attribute value. Then, what should i need to do?

Comment: you need to here only add your attribute code i have recently use this code and create configure products

Comment: Can you please add that in answer and update code?

Comment: @RakeshDonga, did you update the answer as [at]niket asked because I am also looking for the same snippet.. how can I add color and sizes to the product